# Using Azure Devops pipeline and webhook to trigger it, i can not get payload content

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, webhooks, payload, workitem

I'm trying to get the payload content coming from the webhook that trigger the pipeline when a work item is updated.

I have a powershell Task to try to get the content, for example, when a work item is updated, i want to get the System.AreaPath that is in the WorkItem and available in the payload.

```yaml
trigger:
  none
pool:
  name: SYNCCHR

resources:
  webhooks:
    - webhook: GETPAYLOAD          
      connection: GETPAYLOAD_CON 

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Write-Host "${{ parameters.GETPAYLOAD.resource.workItemId }}"
      Write-Host "${{ parameters.GETPAYLOAD.resource.revision.rev }}"
      Write-Host '${{ parameters.GETPAYLOAD.resource.revision.fields.System.AreaPath }}'
```

i don't find a way to get the System.Area value. parameters.GETPAYLOAD is a yaml expression related withe the parameters variable, it is gobal variable built-in in the yaml pipeline in Devops.

The fact the property System.AreaPath contains a dot in the name does not help with yaml syntax !

The payload is containing this kind of json :

[payload content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBQ9d.jpg)

I tried many time different syntax, triggering the pipeline via the update of work item but i can not obtain the content of properties under revision or fields nodes.

The goal is to be able to obtain in powershell task any property in the payload.

Answer (score 0):

i found finally the way to obtain the data concerning System.AreaPath:

the syntax is

```yaml
for the workitem.updated event :
'"${{ parameters.GETPAYLOAD.resource.revision.fields['System.AreaPath'] }}"'
for the workitem.created event :
'"${{ parameters.GETPAYLOAD.resource.fields['System.AreaPath'] }}"'
```